# AS3 image rotate within / scale to fit sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, sprite

We're making bitmap data from a sprite where we want to take an image and rotate within / scale to fit. This is our code, which includes a rotation.

`_rotation` defines how much the user has input.

The problem is, we're getting an output file that is 100% white. 
We think that the image is  rotating about 0x0y therefore rotating the image outside the bounds of the sprite.

Furthermore, the image is not scaling to the child, instead is sort of "cropping" as it inherits.

What is the best way of doing this? Basically we want to take an image and rotate within / scale to fit

```
var sprite1:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(sprite1);
var photoBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(_bitmapData);
sprite1.addChild(photoBitmap);
sprite1.rotation = _rotation;  
var sprite2:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(sprite2);
sprite2.addChild(sprite1);

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite2.width,sprite2.height,false,0xFFFFFF);
bitmapData.draw(sprite2);
```

Comment: That's an example code I'm guessing but it's all wrong and cannot draw anything at all. Do you have something better?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to draw sprite with scaling/rotating is using [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) in method [bitmapData.draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()).

Example:

```
var sourceImage:SomeSprite = new SomeSprite();
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.scale(0.5, 0.5);
matrix.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
var newImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sourceImage.width/2, sourceImage.height/2);
newImage.draw(sourceImage, matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely a cause of rotating around the top left corner (which can make the entire object left of or above the registration point (0 x and 0 y) and not get drawn.

An easy way you can account for this, is to move `sprite1` after the rotation to account for the new size and position caused by rotating:

```
...
sprite2.addChild(sprite1);

var actualPosition:Rectangle = sprite2.getBounds(sprite2); //this gets the new position/dimensions of the object
sprite1.x = -actualPosition.x;
sprite1.y = -actualPosition.y;

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite2.width,sprite2.height,false,0xFFFFFF);
...
```